# Compare products from same category in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, compare

I want to be able to compare 2 products only if they belong to the same category. I am developing a website for health products. Under the health products category link, I am listing all products. Products from different subcategories are also comparable right now. eg. a wheelchair is comparable to a Glucometer, which does not make sense.

I am working on Magento CE 1.9. Has anyone worked on similar requirement? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Editing after @Manoj's answer:

I added 3 files:
`app/etc/modules/mydir_All.xml`

```
app/code/local/mydir/controllers/Product/CompareController.php  
app/code/local/mydir/etc/config.xml  
CompareController.php has only one method addAction() with the code suggested by @Manoj.

Here is the content of mydir_All.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mydir>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </mydir>
    </modules>
</config>

Content of config.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
    <mydir>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </mydir>
</modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <tag>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mydir before="Mage_Catalog">mydir</mydir>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </tag>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Nothing seems to change. Compare products is working as was before.

Comment: Try using this free extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-advanced-compare.html
Key highlight on Features:
1. Disable product compare for specific products.
2. Make product compare more obvious.
3. It's ajax based. 
Good question BTW.

Comment: Someone has posted a solution here as well. 
http://blog.wafa.in/2014/03/magento-compare-product-specified-category/

Comment: I have seen this extension. It does not have this feature. The demo site is letting me compare a bed to a sofa. I anyways tried installing it, but it gives me a 404 error. Some reviews say its not compatible with CE 1.9. I have seen the wafa blog as well, but I could not figure out where exactly that change needs to be made.

Comment: Ok and how about the second link?

Comment: Saw that too. But where exactly do I write the first set of code? Confused :-|

Comment: Try rewriting app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\Product\CompareController.php to a custom module.

Comment: I am not very familiar with PHP coding. I added that code to addAction method but it gives some error.

Comment: This tutorial will show you the way how you override a controller in Magneto. 
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

May be more details on your error can enable us to solve your problem.

Comment: mydir will be Mydir,@Priyanka please create module will proper namespace and overrides if you still struggling use module creator www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. Posting this so it might come handy for people struggling with it.

Here is /app/etc/modules/Company_Catalog.xml (convention is to use Company_Module.xml with first letters in Caps):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_Catalog> <!-- notice Company_Module tag here also -->
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Company_Catalog>
</modules>
</config>
```

Here is /app/code/local/Company/Catalog/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
<Company_Catalog> <!--notice the Company_Catalog tag here -->
<version>0.1.0</version>
</Company_Catalog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <catalog> <!-- this has to be the module name -->
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_Catalog before="Mage_Catalog">Company_Catalog</Company_Catalog> <!--this has to be in one line else newline/ spaces won't be parsed. Notice the before=Mage_ModuleName  -->
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Here is the /app/code/local/Company/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php:

```
<?php

//notice that require_once is calling CompareController.php under the Product directory
    require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'Product'.DS.'CompareController.php');

class Company_Catalog_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController
{
public function addAction() {

    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        return;
    }

    $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

    $productPresent = false;
    $found = array();
    $compareProducts = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();

    $itemCount = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount();


    if($itemCount) {
        $compareProductId = $compareProducts->getFirstItem()->getId();
        $compareProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($compareProductId);
        $compareProductCats = $compareProductCollection->getCategoryIds();

        foreach($categoryIds as $num) {
            if (in_array($num,$compareProductCats)) {
                $found[$num] = true;
            }
        }

        foreach($compareProducts as $products) {
            if($productId == $products->getId()) {
                $productPresent = true;
            }
        }

        //Check if categories of products to be compared are matching
        if(empty($found)){
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError(
                $this->__('You cannot compare %s with the items in the comparison list. Please select products from the same category.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
            );
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }            

    }

    //Add product in comparison list
    if ($productId && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {

        if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The product %s has been added to the comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
            );
            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
        }

        Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
    }

    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
}

?>
```

My suggestion for someone who is trying to rewrite a module for the first time and getting stuck:

1. After adding Company_Module.xml, go and check in System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output that your new module is indeed enabled.
2. System->Tools->Compilation->Disable Compilation
3. System->Cache Management->Disable all cache types.
4. Use echo in the first line of your new class to ensure that your new module is being read by Magento.
5. Not sure if this is the right approach, but to first check if the addAction() logic was correct, I made a copy of /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php; replaced the original addAction() with my new addAction() and tested the logic. Once this was working, I was confident the code was correct and the module was not being read. Then attacked the xmls one by one (or tag by tag :). Ofcourse also replaced the original CompareController.php in core.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you check `addAction` in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\Product\CompareController.php`.

you can overwrite the `CompareController` and in `addAction` before adding product check previous added products are in same category. if not remove previous compare list and add New Product. Here you can save current category id in compare list product catgory session. so you don't need to fetch category IDs everytime for products that are added in compare list.

Hope this help !!

Comment: I am not very familiar with PHP coding.. can you help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code,you need to override app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\Product\CompareController.php.

the addAction will beas mention below

```
public function addAction() {

        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_redirectReferer();
            return;
        }

        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        $productPresent = false;
        $found = array();
        $compareProducts = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection();

        $itemCount = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCount();


        if($itemCount) {
            $compareProductId = $compareProducts->getFirstItem()->getId();
            $compareProductCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($compareProductId);
            $compareProductCats = $compareProductCollection->getCategoryIds();

            foreach($categoryIds as $num) {
                if (in_array($num,$compareProductCats)) {
                    $found[$num] = true;
                }
            }

            foreach($compareProducts as $products) {
                if($productId == $products->getId()) {
                    $productPresent = true;
                }
            }

            //Check if categories of products to be compared are matching
            if(empty($found)){
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addError(
                    $this->__('You cannot compare %s with the items in the comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
                );
                $this->_redirectReferer();
                return;
            }            

        }

        //Add product in comparison list
        if ($productId && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {

            if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The product %s has been added to the comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()))
                );
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
            }

            Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
        }

        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
```

Comment: Can you look at the config.xml and mydir_All.xml I have used and see if I have missed out something?

Comment: please check your naming conventions

Comment: I had actually used Mydir convention only. Thats the name of the company and didn't want to write it in a public forum. Thats why replaced it with mydir. It still does not work.

Comment: Please create new module and then try